# Angular material MatProgressButton disable property is not working?

Tags: angular

I am using npm for button progress ***https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-progress-buttons***

At the time button disable property is not working.

My code

***HTML***

```
<mat-spinner-button type="submit" id="profile-management" [options]="spinnerButtonOptions" ></mat-spinner-button>
```

***TS File***

```
  spinnerButtonOptions: MatProgressButtonOptions = {
        active: false,
        text: 'Save & Next',
        spinnerSize: 25,
        raised: true,
        stroked: false,
        buttonColor: 'primary',
        spinnerColor: 'accent',
        fullWidth: false,
        disabled: false,
        mode: 'indeterminate',
      }
```

Comment: I've tested it and it works. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-it5esa

Comment: In my scenarion if form validation is true,then only enable button .otherwise button goes to disable.***   angular Reactive form***

Comment: you can access `spinnerButtonOptions` variable and change it's properties. on this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-it5esa), the button is disabled first, then enabled after 5 seconds.